# Drupal 7 Search Autocomplete module never loads "suggestions"

Tags: search, autocomplete, drupal-7

I am attempting to use the module Search Autocomplete 7.x-4.0-alpha2.
I have added a form in the "search_autocomplete" configuration section.
It is enabled.
I created a view that returns taxonomy in json format. 
[image]

Here is an example of the json output from the json view

```
[{
    "value": "aquaculture",
    "fields": {
        "name_i18n": "aquaculture"
    },
    "group": {
        "group_id": "aquaculture",
        "group_name": "aquaculture"
    }
}, {
    "value": "climate change",
    "fields": {
        "name_i18n": "climate change"
    },
    "group": {
        "group_id": "climatechange",
        "group_name": "climate change"
    }
}, {
    "value": "coastal development",
    "fields": {
        "name_i18n": "coastal development"
    },
    "group": {
        "group_id": "coastaldevelopment",
        "group_name": "coastal development"
    }
}, {
    "value": "deforestation",
    "fields": {
        "name_i18n": "deforestation"
    },
    "group": {
        "group_id": "deforestation",
        "group_name": "deforestation"
    }
}, {
    "value": "extinction",
    "fields": {
        "name_i18n": "extinction"
    },
    "group": {
        "group_id": "extinction",
        "group_name": "extinction"
    }
}]
```

I set the Suggestion Source to be the view. I used the autocomplete feature of it so I know that my "search autocomplete" suggestion source is configured right.  The id selector of a form in a different view (not the json taxonomy one) is used. The permissions for the module are correct.
Now, when I load my view that has the search api form I see a little blue circle icon that is circling to the right of the search api form field. It is circling the whole time and no suggestions are ever populated in the search text box.
I know I have the right form configured because if I set a different form id for the "searchautocomplete" configuration and reload the view page, the circling blue circle is missing.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

UPDATE: I was going to my modules page and saw this error (i wasn't changing anything on the modules page, just going there) and saw the error on the top of the modules page regarding the Search Autocomplete module

[image]

Update: I changed the Search Autocomplete configuration section to not point to my json view but point to an outside url, http://google.com.  Of course this is not a valid json endpoint, but I wanted to see if I could see it at least attempt to get it's json data from google.com. Watching through firebug has shown that it doesn't even attempt to go to google.com for it's json data. I think something similar is happening with my json views (it's just not even going there for the data).

Answer (score 0):

That was probably due to a bug in the alpha-version? When you configure the JSON Endpoint by using the Views UI, you should see a list of items in the "preview"-section underneath. The items that are listed there should be the ones that appear as suggestions in the search.